# How to recall onCreate( ) when onBackPressed( ) and go to previous activity?

Tags: android, localization

MyApp testing is multi language change. http://www.androhub.com/android-building-multi-language-supported-app/ After I choose radio button, it changes language in current activity. But when I go back previous activity, it doesn't change language. So, I want to recall onCreate when I click back button. Or How to refresh current activity?

**onCreate ()**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    radioEng = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.eng);
    radiohi = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.hi);

    // Initialization
    pref = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = pref.edit();

    radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, @IdRes int i) {
            String lang = "en"; // Default Language
            switch (i) {
                case R.id.eng:
                    lang = "en";
                    break;
                case R.id.hi:
                    lang = "hi";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            changeLocale(lang); // Change Locale on selection basis
        }
    });

    loadLocale();
}
```

**changeLocale**

```
private void changeLocale(String lang) {
    if (lang.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        return;
    Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang); // Set Selected Locale
    saveLocale(lang);   // Save the selected locale
    Locale.setDefault(myLocale);    // set new locale as default
    Configuration config = new Configuration(); // get Configuration
    config.locale = myLocale;   // set config locale as selected locale
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());   // Update the config
}
```

**saveLocale & loadLocale**

```
private void saveLocale(String lang) {
    editor.putString("save", lang);
    editor.commit();
    if (lang.equals("en")) {
        radioEng.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        radiohi.setChecked(true);
    }
}

private void loadLocale() {
    String lang = pref.getString("save", "");
    if (lang.equals("")) {
        radioEng.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        changeLocale(lang);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think don't recall onCreate on back button press. Use onResume to do your logic. For example if you are fetching text and set it as hint on EditText then after coming back on back button pressed just set hint text again as per your need.

Comment: previous activity is already in Task Stack(already in memory), Once you change the language in current activity and press back button it navigates to previous activity in stack. It doesn't reloads the previous activity, it just makes the previous activity visible. So i think it is always better the change the Language in MainActivity or like launcher activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Current_Activity.this,Current_Activity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
```

instantiate a new intent in your `onBackPressed()`

Comment: it doesn't go to previous activity when back press. how to recall onCreate( ) and go to back? Thx.

Comment: do not put the `this.onCreate(null);` in your `onCreate()` but in `onBackPressed()`

Comment: No, can't !!    `@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       this.onCreate(null);
    }`

Comment: sorry my bad. check my latest edit. hopefully it works.

Answer (score 0):

give resultCode when back from current activity, or save configuration, then check configuration on activity resume for language change

Answer (score 0):

You can call onCreate method on back press by handling back press event.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        onCreate(new Bundle()); 
    }
```

If you are using API 11 then use below code and also if above code doesn't work.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: minSdkVersion 15, `Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);` it doesn't go to previous activity when back press. reload current activity

Comment: You want to load previous activity again on back press?

Comment: I want to reload current activity,

Comment: Please clear your requirement because you said "it doesn't go to previous activity when back press. reload current activity".

Comment: I really want to refresh current activity after changing language. And then close all previous activities.

Comment: Then just load current activity again and doesn't store all previous activity in stack. For that first finish() current activity and then call new activity.

Comment: Suppose that if you have 3 activity and on third activity your language is change  than you need change the language in previous two activity, but previous two activity store in stack so they doesn't load again for that when you call activity two from one and three from two just use below code

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Acivity1.class, Activity2.class); startActivity(intent);  finish();

Answer (score 0):

I think you should finish the previous activity and recreate it, you can use LocalBroadcast.

Answer (score 0):

While using the recreate method works by doing

```
this.recreate()
```

It was only added in API level 11. If you want to include more devices you can check the API level and implement both the recreate method as well as

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

You can use both by making an if statement like...

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
//Code for recreate
recreate();

}else{
//Code for Intent
Intent intent = getIntent();
finish();
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using two activities when you create intent from first activity to second activity the first activity onStop() is called and activity is put to back stack.When you press back button the first activity onCreate() is not called again but onResume() is called and activity is resumed.

So the logic that your are trying to should be done in onResume() such that it will be called every time when you press back button.For more reference check this.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html